# nginx serving AngularJS app returns 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx

I am experiencing problems on configuring nginx to serve static angularjs files.

This is my situation, I want the landing page of my application under

```
domain.com
```

and the AngularJS app under

```
domain.com/app
```

Now I am struggling with the nginx configuration. I heve created a nginx server configuration as follows:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public;
    }
}
```

But this is not working, I get this error on Firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://domain.com/app/"
```

Any idea?

---

Ok I made some progress, if I change the following:

```
alias /usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public;
```

to the following:

```
alias /usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public/;
```

(if I use root instead of alias, I get 403 forbidden)

I can now access the application but still I have 404 on assets files, for example one of them is:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/app/assets/images/logo.png"
```

assets are under the directory:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/app/public/app/assets/
```

but for some reason nginx is looking for assets here:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/app/public/assets/
```

any idea?

Comment: Is there an `index.html` file in the folder `/usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public`?

Comment: Yes there is the index.html file and app folder with assets. The strange thing is that this application works fine if I put everything under the root, so I can access it by domain.com.

Comment: Why the difference between `root` and `alias`? Or, though I doubt that, maybe the problem is that `location /app` refers to a subdirectory of the file system folder used in `location /`? Does `http://domain.com/app/public` load the AngularJS `index.html`? (If so, then it's using the mapping for `location /` for that, I guess.)

Comment: do you need a trailing slash after the `/app` in your location block (`location /app/ {`)?

Comment: @Arjan http://domain.com/app/public does not load Angularjs, the error is  the same (404). 
heavyd I changed to /app/ and now I get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I get this error on nginx logs:
2015/05/19 15:02:48 [error] 21155#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public" is forbidden, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"

Comment: What about `http://domain.com/app/index.html` and  `http://domain.com/app/public/index.html` then? And did you see my question about `root` vs `alias`? The error `directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public" is forbidden` would make me think there simply is no folder `/usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com/app/public/` or it has no `index.html` to fall back to in case no specific file is requested. (I'm not an nginx expert though.)

Comment: Check nginx error log, it should have entries about your request and 404 you got.

Comment: You need to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080/132074